# Is the h2o dataframe enum type's internal string-to-int mapping always the same?

Tags: h2o

Looking at the docs for h2o's categorical_encoding `enum` type, it says

> enum or Enum: Leave the dataset as is, **internally map the strings to
>   integers**, and use these integers to make splits - either via ordinal
>   nature when nbins_cats is too small to resolve all levels or via
>   bitsets that do a perfect group split. Each category is a separate
>   category; its name (or number) is irrelevant. For example, after the
>   strings are mapped to integers for Enum, you can split {0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5} as {0, 4, 5} and {1, 2, 3}.

Does this mean that whenever I convert the same (in this case) pandas dataframe to an h2o dataframe, the internal representation for each of any of the categorical `enum` type column values will always be the same (or is it in some way random each time)? (I assume it would have to be in order to be useful for running any actual predictions on a model trained on the dataframe, but want to make sure my understanding is correct).

- As a side note, what does the doc's description mean by "to make splits"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as the categorical levels are the same, the order will be the same and the indices will be in assigned in the same way.

splits are referring to tree based models.